# Use two output columns to create a third output column with SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `SELECT` that computes two numbers for each row, each is one column. I then want to divide the two numbers and show that divided result as a third column.

I feel this should be quite simple (I'm pretty inexperienced with SQL) but I haven't been able to find anything on it - perhaps I'm searching with the wrong keywords.

In other words, I'd like the output to be something like

```
Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3
---------------------
 1        2      0.5
 3        5      0.6
```

where `Col 1` and `Col 2` are both expensive computations and `Col 3` is simply equal to `Col 2 / Col 1`.

Naively I would write this query as:

```
SELECT (expr1) AS "Col 1", (expr2) as "Col 2", (expr1 / expr2) as "Col 3"
```

But here both expressions `expr1` and `expr2` would be evaluated twice. How can I temporarily store the values of `expr1` and `expr2` and use them for `Col 3`?

Edit: I was able to do this with:

```
SELECT "Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 1"/ "Col 2" as "Col 3" 
  FROM (SELECT (expr1) AS "Col 1", (expr2) as "Col 2")
```

Is this the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT (expr1) AS "Col 1", (expr2) as "Col 2"
  FROM ...
)
SELECT "Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 1" / "Col 2" AS "Col 3"
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a cte and that should help you work

```
with cte as
(...(expr1) AS "Col 1", (expr2) as "Col 2 ... )
select "Col 1", "Col 2", ("Col 1" / "Col 2") as "Col 3" from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice method is to use a lateral join:

```
SELECT v.col1, v.col2, (v.expr1 / v.expr2) as col3
FROM T CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (expr1, expr2)) v(col1, col2);
```

Lateral joins make it convenient to chain the results, just be adding more lateral joins.